# getting current directory in linux for argument

Tags: linux

I'm learning Linux scripting and trying to set up a function that finds all files in the current directory. I know I could use ls but I'm wondering if there is a way to get the current directory as a command and pass it to an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash


check_file() {
for f in $1: 
do
    echo $f
done
}

check_file pwd
```

This just prints out pwd:, which obviously isn't it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`PWD` variable does exactly what you want.
So just replace `pwd` with `$PWD` and you are done

Answer (score 6):

To execute a command and use its output in your script as a parameter, just use back quotes.
In your case, it would be:

```
check_file `pwd`
```

Answer (score 4):

A more modern variant is to use the `$(`...`)` notation (which can be nested when needed, and is expanded to the output of the command in between `$(` and matching `)`) instead of the backquotes, eg

```
check_file $(pwd)
```

(but `$PWD` would work too since shells maintain their `PWD` variable, see [Posix shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)).

Read also the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (which can be criticized but is a good start).

Answer (score 1):

**$PDW** 
the present working directory is stored in the variable named $PWD

```
check_file()
 {
  for f in "$(ls $PWD)" 
   do
    echo "$f"
    done
 }
check_file
```

**Display the full working directory name**

```
echo "$PWD"
```

**Display the working directory name**

```
basename "$PWD"
```

**Can also use the symbol *** 
is a short cut to a list of files in the present working directory .

```
echo *
```

**Loop through them** :

```
for item in *
 do
  echo "$item"
 done
```

**Function looping through**

```
check_file()
 {
  for f in * 
   do
    echo "$f"
   done
 }
check_file
```

**Store the present directory name in a variable and use it in a function**

```
Var=$(basename "$PWD")

func()
{
 echo $1
}
func $Var
```